# Translate Animation Android

Tags: android, android-studio, animation, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView with Images inside. I need to move clicked image to the center of the screen. And there should be no depend on the images's start point, it should move to the center of the screen.

I've tried to do this using XML code - it does't work correct, TranslateAnimation object - it doesn't work correct. In both variants image's movement depends on the images's start position and final points of all images are different.

I don't know how to do this. Please help me)

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code. The code uses Listview, but the same logic can be applied for RecyclerView.

The approach here is to create a new imageview in the parent layout of the listview overlapping the image that was clicked. Then translate the newly created imageview to the center of the screen.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    root = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_root);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, web, imageId);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            ImageView imgView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);

            // Get location of window with respect to window.
            int location[] = new int[2];
            imgView.getLocationInWindow(location);

            // Create a new image view overlapping
            // the image view that was clicked.
            ImageView imgView2 = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
            imgView2.setImageDrawable(imgView.getDrawable());

            // To make it overlap, use the location values of
            // the clicked image as left and top margin for the
            // new image.
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    imgView.getWidth(), imgView.getHeight());
            params.leftMargin = location[0];
            params.topMargin  = location[1] - getStatusBarHeight();

            // Add the new image view to the root view of the activity.
            root.addView(imgView2, params);

            translateToCenter(imgView2, location);
        }
    });

}

/**
 * To translate the new image view to the center of the screen.
 * @param view
 * @param originalLoc
 */
private void translateToCenter(View view , int originalLoc[])
{
    int xMove = root.getWidth() / 2 - view.getWidth() / 2  - originalLoc[0];
    int yMove = root.getHeight() / 2 - view.getHeight() / 2 - originalLoc[1];

    TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation( 0, xMove , 0, yMove );
    anim.setDuration(1000);
    anim.setFillAfter( true );
    view.startAnimation(anim);
}

/**
 * To get the status bar height.
 * @return
 */
private int getStatusBarHeight() {
    int result = 0;
    int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(
            "status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0) {
        result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    }
    return result;
}
```